# Вырезание фона на фотографии в ios приложении

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, изображения, iphone

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вырезать фон у фотографии в приложении? 
Т.е. пользователь фотографирует какой-то объект, а приложение должно убрать с этой фотографии фон.

Предполагается, что фон будет однородный.

Цвет фона заранее будет известен.

Я находил в AppStore приложения с таким функционалом (вот [например](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/id335709058?mt=8)), значит решение этой задачи уже найдено.

Если у кого-то есть опыт разработки подобных приложений, поделитесь, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

[ACKategories](https://github.com/AckeeCZ/ACKategories/tree/master/ACKategories/UIKit) имеет хорошую [реализацию](https://github.com/AckeeCZ/ACKategories/blob/master/ACKategories/UIKit/UIImage%2BColor.h) замены одного цвета другим. А в целом задача простая и есть масса реализаций. Например в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12396236/1254172) вопросе есть куча вариантов.